# Extract values from a div and save it in an array - JSFindle given

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

When a user clicks on the `add a row` button, a pair of text fields namely `username` and `password` will appear as shown in the [jsfiddle link below](https://jsfiddle.net/5no9001w/).

Now, when the user submits the form by clicking on the `send` button, I want to extract the username and password pairs and save it in an array (as key-value pairs). So that, 1 array can have one or many pairs of username-password objects saved.

How can I do this. My working so far can be found in the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5no9001w/).

Note: I already know how to save the username and password in to an array:

```
var dict = {};

dict['username'] = "password";
```

Comment: NB: it is fiddle, not findle, and your array is not an array but plain object ;-)

Comment: You can just do `dict['username2'] = "password2"; dict['username3'] = "password3"; ....`

Comment: The thing is the number of `username-password` pairs are unknown to me. The user keeps adding by clicking on the `add a row button` which appears on the top left hand corner on the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the new elements by cloning you forget to change the id because they must be unique. Moreover, you forget to reset the values.

If you add the id to password field you may address the problem like in the following snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    counter++; //Increase counter
    var clonedBox = $('.input-group').eq(0).clone();
    clonedBox.find('input').attr('id', function(index, attr) {
      return attr + (counter - 1);
    }).val('');
    $("#boxid").append(clonedBox);
    $( "#boxid .countid" ).last().text('UserId'+counter);

    clonedBox = $('.input-group').eq(1).clone();
    clonedBox.find('input').attr('id', function(index, attr) {
      return attr + (counter - 1);
    }).val('');
    $("#boxid").append(clonedBox);
  });

  // WHEN CLICKED ON SUBMIT RETRIEVE ALL DATA\\
  $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
    //alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );

    var dict = {};

    $('#target input[id^="myid"]').each(function(i, e) {
      dict[this.value] = $('#mypwdid' + ((i == 0) ? '' : i)).val();
    })

    console.log('Fields '+ JSON.stringify(dict));




    event.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```css
.input-group{
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Add  row</button>
<form id="target" method="POST">
    <div id="boxid">
        <div id="boxcontainerid" class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="countid input-group-addon">UserId</div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myid" placeholder="username" name="1">
                <div class="input-group-addon">?</div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">Password</div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="mypwdid" placeholder="password">
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>

    </div>
    <button>send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: When I click on the `Add a row` button, the previously entered text gets copied to the newly added textbox. how can i get rid of it ?

Answer (score 1):

The `dict` object can receive any number of new key/value pairs.

Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5no9001w/1/), as this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    counter++; //Increase counter
    $('.input-group').clone().appendTo("#boxid").find(':text').val(''); 
    $("#boxid .countid" ).last().text('UserId'+counter);
  });

  // WHEN CLICKED ON SUBMIT RETRIEVE ALL DATA\\
  $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
    //alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );

    var dict = {};
    $("input[name=name]").each(function (i) {
      dict[$(this).val()] = $('input[name=pwd]').eq(i).val();
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(dict, null, 2));
    event.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```css
.input-group{
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Add  row</button>
<form id="target" method="POST">
  <div id="boxid">
    <div id="boxcontainerid" class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="countid input-group-addon">UserId</div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="username">
        <div class="input-group-addon">?</div>
      </div>

      <div class="input-group"> 
        <div class="input-group-addon">Password</div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>

  </div>
  <button>send</button>
</form>
```

Note that you cannot have duplicate `id` attribute values in HTML, so I removed the `id` on the user name `input` element, and used `name="name"` instead.

Comment: i think that works. I have another tiny bug in this code. When I click on the `Add row` button the previously entered text appears on the newly added textboxes. How can I clear these text values?

Comment: You can copy both input areas at once, and then find the inputs in them, and clear them with `val('')`, like this: `$('.input-group').clone().appendTo("#boxid").find(':text').val('');`. I updated my snippet.